# AddDays in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a stored procedure which has 2 parameters @from, @to, I want to pass @from the value of $from, which is inputed from powershell GUI. I want @to to be 1 day after @from. I have below code.  Which value seems to be passed to @from, but to value is not passed. Any suggestion?

```
$param1=$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@from" , [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime)
$param1.Value=Get-Date $from -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
$param2=$sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@to", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime)
$param2.Value=Get-Date ($from).AddDate(1) -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly from your previous question, `$from` is a string, not a date. You can't add days to a string, so you need to convert it to a date first. Also you need `.AddDays(1)`, not `.AddDate(1)`.

```
$param2.Value = Get-Date (Get-Date $from).AddDays(1) `
  -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"
```

Comment: thanks, it's working, however, even I can see the value of $param1 and $param2 is what I wanted, powershell now throw an error said I didn't supply the value for @from

Comment: @Apriljuly Without seeing the actual error message there isn't much I can do about that.